# Tensorflow path in conda enviroment

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

Each time I try to create a python environment with conda it uses my .local/lib/python3.6/site-packages path as the file path for the python packages, I noticed this because when trying to use tensorflow.

**this is the command that i use to create the conda env**

```
conda create -n tensorflow_od pip python=3.9
```

** then activate the environment with

```
conda activate tensorflow_od
```

**this is what I get when I check the tensorflow that is used within the environment using "pip show tensorflow"**

*Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.3.0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: packages@tensorflow.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /home/nwoke/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: absl-py, astunparse, gast, google-pasta, grpcio, h5py, keras-preprocessing, numpy, opt-einsum, protobuf, scipy, six, tensorboard, tensorflow-estimator, termcolor, wheel, wrapt
Required-by: tensorflow-io, tensorflow-text, tf-models-official*

How can I resolve this

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little vague to be honest, but here is my understanding of it. You have not used the command `conda activate tensorflow_od` to activate the virtual environment `tensorflow_od`. You are calling `pip show tensorflow` from the base environment which is resulting in `/home/nwoke/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages` being shown as your tensorflow location.

Do one thing,

1. `conda activate tensorflow_od` use this command to activate your virtual environment.
2. After you see that your venv is active, `pip show tensorflow` would give an output of `WARNING: Package(s) not found: tensorflow`.
3. `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow`.
4. Then again call `pip show tensorflow`, it will point to the venv installation of tensorflow.

Comment: Hello, sorry for not specifying earlier I actually activate the environment with "pip show tensorflow" . Then  when I run "pip show tensorflow"  within the environment even without installing tensorflow it points to tensorflow in "/home/nwoke/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages"

Comment: `pip show tensorflow` does not activate the environment.
Anyways, it might be possible that pip is pointing to the root installation. To check, open a python instance 
`import tensorflow as tf` 
`print(tf.__file__)`
it should point to the venv installation of tf